# Using data.table to summarize monthly sequences (count specific events)

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I hope this is an acceptable R/data.table problem.

I have a 3-column table with:

- `id` geographic location IDs (303,453 locations)
- `month` month over 25 years 1990-2014
- `spei` a climatic index that varies between -7 and 7.

I need to count the occurrence of droughts at each location over the entire 1990-2014 period. A drought event is defined as "*a period in which the SPEI is continuously negative and the SPEI reaches a value of -1.0 or less. Drought starts when the SPEI first falls below zero and ends with the first positive SPEI value following a value of -1.0 or less*".

I know this should be feasible using shift() and rolling joins but would very welcome some help!

```
# Sample table structure
dt <- data.table(
  id = rep(1:303453, each=25*12),
  month = rep(seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "month"), 303453),
  spei = runif(303453*25*12, -7, 7))

# A minimal example with 1 location over 12 months
library(data.table)
library(xts)

dt <- data.table(
  id = rep("loc1", each=12),
  month = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "month"),
  spei = c(-2, -1.1, -0.5, 1.2, -1.2, 2.3, -1.7, -2.1, 0.9, 1.2, -0.9, -0.2))

spei.ts <- xts(dt$spei, order.by=dt$month, frequency="month")
plot(spei.ts, type="bars")
```

[image]

This shows 3 drought events over a 1-year period. This is what I need to identify and count.

Hoping some of you are more used to working with time series.
Many thanks, --Mel.

Comment: Please post with a small reproducible example and expected output for easier understanding and crosschecking

Comment: I doubt that `rep(1:303453, each=25*12)` could be considered as **small** reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point to get the result you want.
Probably experts can suggest improvements in speed.

**EDIT:** improved speed ~8x by removing `paste`.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
n <- 300  # 303453 will be ~1000 times slower
dt <- data.table(
    id = rep(1:n, each=25*12),
    month = rep(seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "month"), n),
    spei = runif(n*25*12, -7, 7))

system.time({
  dt[, `:=`(neg = (spei < 0), neg1 = (spei <= -1))]
  dt[, runid := ifelse(neg, rleid(neg), NA)]
  res <- dt[!is.na(runid), 
            .(length = .N[any(neg1)], start = min(month), end = max(month)), 
            by = .(id, runid)][!is.na(length)]

})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.345   0.000   0.344 

# counts of droughts per id:
res[, .(nDroughts = .N), by = id]

# list of droughts per id: (NB: don't include 1st positive value after) 
res[, .(droughtN = seq_len(.N), start, end), by = id]
```

Comment: This is a good approach, and fast, but I think it's not quite correct. Look at `dt[ id == 1 & year(month) %in% 2006:2007 ]` -- there is a run there that should be starting at "2007-01-01" not "2006-12-01". It starts when it dips below -1 not when it dips below zero.

Comment: @Frank In the question it says: _"Drought starts when the SPEI first falls below zero ..."_, so I would disagree.

Comment: @Max this looks good and runs under 12 sec on my 92 million-row real-life data.table! Had never used `rleid()` before. Thanks very much for pointing this one out

Answer (score 2):

Update based on comment...

If all that was needed was the counts then

```
# Let 'sp' = starting point of potential drought
# Let 'dv' = drought level validation
# The cumsum just gives unique ids to group by.
dt[, sp := (spei <= 0) & (shift(spei, fill = 1) > 0), by = id]
dt[, dv := min(spei) <= -1, by = .(id, cumsum(sp))]
dt[sp & dv, .N, by = id]
```

yet, as stated in the comments, you've already been there, so you've seen how `shift` can be used. Since you like the idea of identifying the dates as well. Why not use `shift` there as well?

```
# Extending the previous columns...
dt[, ep := (shift(spei, type = "lead", fill = 1) > 0) & (spei <= 0), by = id]
cbind(dt[sp & dv, .(start = month), by = id],
      dt[ep & dv, .(end = month), by = id][,id := NULL])
```

If you wanted the dates to be as indicated by the red lines in the plot just add a month unless its the last one. We can also get the lengths too...

```
# Extending the previous columns again...
dt[, end.month := shift(month, type = "lead", fill = month[.N]), by = id]
dt[, orig.id := .I]
starts <- dt[sp & dv][, did := .I]
ends <- dt[ep & dv][, did := .I]
starts[ends, on = "did"][
  ,.(id = id, length = 1 + i.orig.id - orig.id, start = month, end = i.end.month)]
```

Would yield

```
     id length      start        end
1: loc1      3 2014-01-01 2014-04-01
2: loc1      1 2014-05-01 2014-06-01
3: loc1      2 2014-07-01 2014-09-01
```

And it is still *fast*! With `n=300`

```
> microbenchmark(max = max.full(copy(dt))[, .(nDroughts = .N), by = id],
+                thellcounts = thell.counts(copy(dt)),
+                thell .... [TRUNCATED] 
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
         max 218.19152 220.30895 342.18605 222.75507 250.36644 1350.15847    10
 thellcounts  20.36785  22.27349  28.45167  23.39313  24.38610   78.25046    10
  thelldates  28.24378  28.64849  30.59897  30.57793  31.25352   34.51569    10
 thelldates2  36.19724  39.79588  42.34457  41.52455  42.41872   57.28073    10
```

With `n=3000`

```
> microbenchmark(max = max.full(copy(dt))[, .(nDroughts = .N), by = id],
+                thellcounts = thell.counts(copy(dt)),
+                thell .... [TRUNCATED] 
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
         max 2126.1138 2148.3453 2207.7801 2205.3536 2241.2848 2340.1203    10
 thellcounts  197.7312  202.4817  234.2949  205.4828  304.1556  309.1028    10
  thelldates  261.9889  264.5597  283.9970  266.1244  267.8603  374.6406    10
 thelldates2  320.6352  331.7558  374.4110  340.2668  439.1490  441.8473    10
```

Comment: yes this was my first approach as well, tallying the number of times we see shifts from a negative to a positive SPEI index, and then identifying which of these negative streaks also go below `-1`. Grouping by `cumsum(sp)` is smart. @Max approach above has the added benefit of pinpointing start and end months, which is extremely useful as well.